Poor quality jump starter or poor quality battery?
I have 2 jump starters.  One is a Halfords brand lithium 3l jump starter which retails for £90 and the other is a
RING RJS010 500A LITHIUM Jump starter for £75.
My civic coupe was idle for some time but didn’t drop below 3 volts.  The battery did have to be replaced but I was able to repeatedly use the Halfords jump starter to start it.  A full charge would give me at least 4 jump starts if not more.  I was quite impressed.  Even when down to 2/4 power bars I believe it still jump started the vehicle.  Given this performance I thought a jump starter was well worth the investment.
I then bought above mentioned ring brand which was to jump start my hyundai coupe 2006.  The battery had been idle some months I believe there maybe a parasitic drain issue aswell so the battery was at 0 volts. I bought the ring specifically because it has a boost function which allows jumping 0 volt cars which the Halfords does not.l and is limited to 3 volt batteries.
So bought the fresh ring jump starter and it was showing full 4 bars. Gave it 15 minutes charge just to be sure it was still on 4 bars.  Go to jump start car using the boost function and it works.  I stalled the car I think 3 times after which it had gone down to 2/4 bars and was no longer able to start the car and I had to borrow jump leads.
This left me quite disappointed as I paid £75 and it wasn’t reliable like the halford product.  In order to use it again I’d have to charge it. Caused me a lot of Stress - people moving the car etc and made me feel like investing in high quality jump leads would have been a better option.
My question is, is it the case that the products are of different quality or is it perhaps to do with the fact that the Hyundai battery was significantly drained at 0 volts but the civic near 3 volts - hence the degree of drainage causes the jump starter to use more of its charge hence I only got 2-3 starts with the ring product as opposed to the halford which gave me a number. If thats the case maybe the ring will be more reliable once the Hyundai has been charged above 3 volts?
On a side note, if it is relating to the degree of drainage, perhaps it’s not worth buying jump starters for their ability to start completely flat batteries since you’ll only get a few starts out of them anyway before you need to recharge/use jump leads.
Thanks.

For the money spent on jump starters instead of maintaining your vehicle at much lower cost, are you avoiding possible car battery/cables/alternator/drive belt issues that leave your Civic at very low battery voltage, requiring repeated jump starts? Good standby battery voltage should be around 12.5, not requiring jump starts. Voltage below 11 volts can damage and reduce battery life if left this way for days or weeks. Inexpensive trickle chargers left connected to the car battery will recharge and maintain a battery for the life of its warranty, sometimes extending it. Without a garage, driving your Civic once a week for an hour should allow the charging system to fully charge the battery. If after a week of non use and the battery voltage drops below 11 volts, the battery/its cables and connections/drive belt/alternator should be checked. Free battery and alternator tests can be performed by auto stores selling car batteries, in the interests of generating business. Jump starters are generally relied on for the occasional dead battery, not for everyday use for a depleted/discharged/damaged battery.

These jump starters are optimized to provide high current. They generally don't have high capacity. For example a typical USB power bank has far more energy than a typical jump stater.
For example, my Noco GB40 gives 1000 amperes but has only 24 watt-hours in the battery, and has a 3.6 V * 3 = 10.8 V battery. So the 1000 amperes are 10800 watts.
Therefore, at full current, it's depleted in 8 seconds. Few jump starts could do that.
Also if you leave it connected for any length of time to a car battery, a battery could very well take 50 amperes of charging current. That's 540 watts. So keeping it connected to a flat battery for slightly less than 3 minutes would make the jump starter flat, even if you don't actually start the car.
The GB40 is marketed as "up to 20 jump starts" -- note "up to". Here "up to" probably means the environment is warm and the engine is small and not a diesel.
So you got 3 jump starts from the jump starter. Not ideal, but sounds like typical performance from a jump starter that's intended for the size of engine you have. If you want better performance, you need a better jump starter.
Next time, if you're not in a hurry and have a tendency to stall an engine, do a jump start, then leave the car idling for 15 minutes, then you have enough charge in the battery to not need the jump starter.
If 15 minutes doesn't provide enough charge to the battery to avoid the need of further jump starts, it's possible that the battery is ruined and you need a new battery.
Jump starting a car with a ruined battery isn't recommended. Jump start should be reserved only for situations where the battery is good but flat. The ruined battery doesn't buffer the electrical system well, which could lead to voltage spikes, which could destroy expensive electronics in the car. Car electronics are supposed to be protected against that, but then again we so often hear about damage from jump starts that maybe the protection isn't good enough.

When you said get a more powerful jump starter, did u mean get a 3l one instead of 2l even though u will be using on a 2l car.   I asked ring about whether there was any point buying their 3l version they said no if your cars 2l there’s no point.  Is that incorrect or what are you referring to by buy a more powerful ones? Thanks.

When you say next time leave car running for 15 minutes, do you mean if the car stalls it will start up again without a jump? I can imagine this works for good batteries that have depleted but am I right I’m saying there maybe batteries which are depleted so bad that they will not be able to start after 15 minutes but if you put them on a battery charger they will recharge, as such u won’t have to buy a new battery?

Jump starters are not measured in liters but in joules or amperes, but sellers often describe them in liters. Remember that liters is a nonscientific rating. But yes, if your car has a 2 liter engine, DON'T ever buy a 2 liter jump starter. If will work few times if the temperature is not freezing and then it's out of juice. It will not work if the temperature is freezing. I would actually recommend buying at least twice the liters, so for a 2 liter car, buy a 4 liter jump starter.

If your battery doesn't accept enough charge in 15 minutes to be able to start the engine again without the assist of a jump starter, it's done. Stop jumping it and get a new battery already!

Ae you avoiding possible battery/cables/alternator/drive belt issues that leave your Civic at very low battery voltage, requiring repeated jump starts? Alternator/belt drive systems are designed to supply all electrical needs and simultaneously recharge the starting battery. Replacing the battery and still needing a jump pack suggests you're not addressing the alternator/drive belt/pulley systems. Most auto stores selling car batteries should be able to provide a free battery and alternator test, removed for bench or in car testing. An alternator should output at least 13.5 volts at idle.
